# how to reuse effect instance on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

On mootools I'm used to declare once and reuse often. An FX example would go like this:

```
myEffect1 = new Fx.Slide($('myElement1'));
```

How should I go on jQuery? Meaning, the docs make it straightfoward to use:

```
$('myElement1').click(function(e){
    this.slideToggle();
});
```

But if I want to call this effect somewhere else on my code will I have to re-declare it? And  isn't this approach more resource hungry than the one above? How would this be properly done on jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just manually cache the result set in a variable before calling the function, then reuse the function as needed:

```
var $el_one = $("#path .to > .selection"), // Stores jQuery object
    $el_two = $("#path .to > .second");    // Stores jQuery object

var effect = function(){
    $el_one.fadeIn();
    $el_two.fadeOut();
}
```

Now you can call effect any time without reselecting the items. They instead use the cached jQuery selection to animate correctly.

If you need more clarity, let me know.

Comment: This is perfect. As jQuery $() returns a jQuery object and not the element it will work just like on Mootools. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var slideToggleEffect = function(e){
    this.slideToggle();
};

$('myElement1').click(slideToggleEffect);
$('myElement2').click(slideToggleEffect);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Nevertheless you code does not create a reusable instance of the effect. It reuses a function - which is great - but still requires SIZZLE to go over all the elements every time you use the click event if you are animating other element than the one clicked.

Comment: JQuery is centered around object that is created via jQuery(...) or $(...).

Try playing with jQuery.fn.slideToggle.

Comment: Thanks HappyCoder! You comment and dcneiner answer made perfect sense now. Its just that mootools returns an element on $() and jQuery returns an object. Have to get used to that.

Comment: jQuery.fn.slideToggle.apply(jQueriedElement);

But it still requires to call jQuery(...) on DOM element anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a plugin in this case. For example here's a plugin that I use often - a very simple slide and fade toggle effect.

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, "fast", easing, callback);
};
```

Now you can call slideFadeToggle on any selector like this:

```
$("#somedom").slideFadeToggle();
```

Comment: Even though it is not what I was looking this a great input Andy, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you often use the same function across the application it will be very efficient to store it in $.fn (which is the same as $.prototype). Every newly created jQuery('#element') will inherit everything from $.fn.

Answer (score 1):

Since every command acts on a jQuery object (the object returned by calling `$()` on a selector), the example you've given is the nearest comparison to what you're used to in MooTools, as far as I can see.

Is it more resource hungry? Well, that's a complex question to answer as instantiating objects is only one piece of client side code. [Some framework methods for performing certain operations are better in some situations and worse in others](http://dante.dojotoolkit.org/taskspeed/).

Comment: Thanks Russ! Actually I was concerned on having to put Sizzle to work every time I called the XYZ effect because it's triggered by several different elements. To store the $('animated_element') result and then reuse it as dcneiner pointed out makes it more Moo-like.

Comment: @Frankie - absolutely cache a jQuery object in a local variable if it will be used more than once. I think that's the third rule of jQuery club (oh dear, I've broken rules one and two) :)